# Flutter CupertinoButton color always grey

Tags: dart, flutter

Hello I have the following dart code and I want the CupertinoButton to be orange but no matter what I do it stays grey. I have tried changing it to a different color and it still stays grey.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());


class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

    return  new MediaQuery(
    data: new MediaQueryData(),
    child: new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
      child: new Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        child: new Scaffold(
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                new CupertinoButton (
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  child:
                  new Text("Get Started",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoButton-class.html). If you don't provide the onPressed a call back function, the button will be disabled.

To make it enable you can pass a empty function like this.

```
new CupertinoButton (
              onPressed: ()=>{},
              color: Colors.orange,
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
              child:
              new Text("Get Started",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to set `onPressed:` to a valid value. Without it, your button is disabled, per the docs. My IDE actually throws an error without it.

Also, `onPressed: ()=>{}` doesn't work for me, but `onPressed: null` does to disable the CupertinoButton manually. So for my app, I set `onPressed` to null if validation fails with a ternary.

Example:

`onPressed: ()=> $myBoolVarTrue ? _myFunction() : null`